# как закончить строку в python 3 , без кавычек?

Tags: python

пишу программу которая добавляет текст в отдельный файл через `.write(input())`, мне надо сделать так, чтобы каждый новый элемент писался на новой строке. При попытке написать \n выдает ошибку. Программа выглядит вот так:

```
print('что вы хотите сделать?')
inp = input('дополнить список/прочитать список')
if inp == 'дополнить список':
    addfile = open('pyhon.txt', 'a')
    addpoint = input()
    addfile.write(addpoint)
elif inp == 'прочитать список':
    readfile = open('pyhon.txt', 'r')
    print(readfile.read())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, так работает:

```py
print('что вы хотите сделать?')
inp = input('дополнить список/прочитать список')
if inp == '1':
    addfile = open('pyhon.txt', 'a')
    addpoint = input()
    # Тут я добавил + "\n" чтобы добавить новую строку
    addfile.write(addpoint + "\n")
elif inp == '2':
    readfile = open('pyhon.txt', 'r')
    print(readfile.read())
```

Не понимаю, как у вас не работало, но так работает. Ошибок нет.